# "App Installation Not Safe" Showing message and App Closes

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services, mobile-application, appinstaller

I recently updated my Android app via the Play Store, but I'm running into an issue. When I try to open the app, I get a **"App installation is not safe, Please download the app via a proper method"** message, and then the app closes.

Interestingly, this problem doesn't occur when I install the app through other methods. Any insights on why this is happening and how to fix it would be appreciated.

Why is this issue happening? What's the solution?

[image: App installation not safe]